# AJAX request works with .click() but not .submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This code works:

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    <a id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block login">Log in</a>
</form>

$('#login').click(function() { 
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.domain.com/includes/login.php",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(data)
            {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + data );
            },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("fail");
        }
    })
});
```

However, it only lets me execute the AJAX request by clicking the log in button, not pressing enter.

I've tried to find a way around it, but the two methods I've come up with do nothing - no errors.

```
// method 1 - change .click() to .submit()

<form id="myform" action="" method="">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    <a id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block login">Log in</a>
</form>

$('#login').submit(function() { 
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.domain.com/includes/login.php",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(data)
            {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + data );
            },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("fail");
        }
    })
});

// method 2 - change .click() to .submit() and #login to #myform

<form id="myform" action="" method="">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    <a id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block login">Log in</a>
</form>

$('#myform').submit(function() { 
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.domain.com/includes/login.php",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(data)
            {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + data );
            },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("fail");
        }
    })
});
```

How can I allow form submission by either clicking the button or pressing enter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use submit but with preventDefault

Log in

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.domain.com/includes/login.php",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(data)
            {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + data );
            },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("fail");
        }
    })
});
```

Edit: Not sure you can have a type="submit" on a link can you?  If the link doesn't trigger the form submit change it to a button instead

Edited HTML:

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    <button id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block login">Log in</button>
</form>
```

[See it working](http://jsfiddle.net/vK8yB/)  You can style a `button`element to look like a link if you want with CSS

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid this gives me the same result as before - no submission (even with clicking) and no errors.

Comment: See my edit.  `type="submit"` is valid for `input` and `button` elements but not for `a` as far as I know.  Which emans the link ins't triggering a submit.  Return will only trigger submit if there is a submit button to trigger.

Comment: If you really want to use an <a> anchor see my edit below (specifically the "onclick" added to the <a> tag that submits the form.

Comment: @themerlinproject: you would also need to add a (possibly hidden) submit button to get the return to trigger a submit I think.

Comment: or monitor keypress but, sheesh, that seems like a lot of unnecessary code when a regular submit button does it already :p

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    <a id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block login" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">Log in</a>
</form>
```

```
$('#myform').on('submit',function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax
        ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.domain.com/includes/login.php",
        data: $('myform').serialize(),
        success: function(data)
            {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + data );
            },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("fail");
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: this won't trigger with the return key

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There's a typo in there somewhere - discounting the `'` before `click`, I get the error `Unexpected token )`.

Comment: I changed 'click' to 'submit' as the 'click' handler won't handle the form being submitted via the enter button

Comment: I also added back in the preventDefault to prevent the default behavior of the html form while allowing your ajax call to work